# Getting started with openid4java on XAMPP?

Tags: java, linux, xampp, openid

Noob here trying to install openid4java so that I can create an OpenID provider.

How should I start?

I've downloaded openid4java, working with XAMPP and OpenSuse.

Answer (score 0):

You want to install openid4java on your system right? You can try native package method.